# How do I make the camera follow two objects at .5 influence each in blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine, constraints, parent

In blender, in the constraints tab, I can parent the camera to two objects, both with 50% influence. Now in the blender game engine, I have not found a way to do this.  When I start my game, the constraints I set don't do anything in the game engine.

Comment: You can't parent to two objects. Parenting per definition belongs to a single parent (but multiple children). Could it be you want a linear interpolation of the location of two or more objects? Or do you want the camera to show these object within it's view?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of attempting to give the camera multiple parents (which is impossible, an object can have unlimited children, but only one parent) you can put an object in between your two other objects that dynamically moves to the new average position.

```
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
one = scene.objects["one"]
two = scene.objects["two"]

sense = cont.sensors["Always"]

if sense.positive:
    PosX = two.worldPosition.x + one.worldPosition.x
    PosY = two.worldPosition.y + one.worldPosition.y
    PosZ = two.worldPosition.z + one.worldPosition.z

    print(PosX, PosY, PosZ)

    own.worldPosition = (PosX/2, PosY/2, PosZ/2)`
```

The code looks like that. You will notice that it is simply taking the average of position on each axis and applying it to the new object. Now all you have to do is make your camera track the center object, which will dynamically place itself in the right position.

Please note that there is probably an easier way to get the average, but seeing as I am fairly terrible at python, this is the best I can come up with. THe workflow, however is the correct one.

here is the test file:

[image]